# how to make a CMTime reference with a NSTimeInterval

Tags: swift, swift2, cmtime

I need help making a CMTime variable in swift 2 so I can create a AVMutableCompostion. Current code:

```
    let videoAsset: AnyObject! = AVAsset(URL: outputFileURL)

    let videoDuration:CMTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(videoAsset.duration), 1)
```

but the variable videoDuration above keeps returning nil! I double checked to make sure the videoAsset.duration was not nil and it is not.

Abstract: leads it to crash here at the line where "videoDuration" is passed in as a peramiter

```
    // Merge audio and video tracks to complete video
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    do {
        try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration),
            ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] ,
            atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch _ {
        /* TODO: Finish migration: handle the expression passed to error arg: kCMTimeZero */
    }
```

Please help! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are casting `videoAsset` to an AnyObject. Don't do that. It wants to be an AVAsset. Let it be one.

Another problem is that you are not obeying the rules for how to get an AVAsset's `duration`. You cannot simply create an AVAsset and immediately ask for its `duration`. This property (like many others) requires time to acquire. Please read the documentation on [AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading).

Comment: It was working fine before Swift 2.0?? The only thing thats giving me a problem is the CMTime parameter